# What is an alternative approach to looping when comparing arrays?

Tags: python, numpy, loops

I am trying to combine two arrays `lidar_PC` (m x 5) and `depth_PC` (n x 5) based on the first two columns. Both values (phi and theta) have to be the same in order for the point to be added to a new array `final_PC`. If phi and theta are the same, the data from the other 3 columns is also kept.

Below is an example of two arrays combined into an output array, where green rows are the rows to be added into the output array (since phi and theta are the same):

[image: example arrays]

At the moment I am just looping through the array, which understandably takes too much time. What would be a better/faster way of doing this?

```py
'''Combine lidar and camera point clouds'''

def combined_PC(depth_im, lidar_data, cam_labels, lidar_labels, color_im, plot = False):
    '''load data'''
    pc = point_cloud_cam(depth_im, cam_labels, color_im)
    depth_PC = polar_cam(pc)
    lidar_PC = polar_lidar(lidar_data, lidar_labels)

    '''
    set variables
    '''
    theta_cam = depth_PC[:,0]
    phi_cam = depth_PC[:,1]
    r_cam = depth_PC[:,2]
    label_cam = depth_PC[:,3]
    label_lane = depth_PC[:,4]

    new_data = [] #this will contain the merged information
    count = 0
    phi_old = -1
    theta_old = -1

    '''
    Only add to the merged point cloud the combination of phi and thetas
    that appear in both camera and lidar
    '''
    start = timer()
    for i in range(len(lidar_PC)):
        [theta,phi,r, label_l] = lidar_PC[i]

        if phi == phi_old and theta == theta_old:
            count += 1
            '''In case there is more than one radius for a set of phi and theta (len(depth_t2)>1)'''
            new_data.append([theta,phi,r,depth_t2[count][2],label_l, depth_t2[count][3],depth_t2[count][4]])

        else:

            if phi in phi_cam:
                idx_d = (depth_PC[:,1]==phi)
                depth_t = depth_PC[idx_d,:]

                if theta in theta_cam:
                    idx_d2 = (depth_t[:,0]==theta)
                    depth_t2 = depth_t[idx_d2,:] #depth_t2 can have more than one entry due to rounding to 2 decimal places

                    if len(depth_t2) != 0:
                        '''
                        Add to new array in the format (Theta, phi, r_lidar, r_camera, label_lidar, label_camera, lane_label)
                        '''
                        new_data.append([theta,phi,r,depth_t2[0][2], label_l, depth_t2[0][3], depth_t2[0][4]])

                        theta_old,phi_old = theta, phi #keep track of the values added to new_data
    end = timer()
    print("Time for the loop = ", end - start)

    final_PC = np.array(new_data)
```

Comment: it would be better to share a sample  arrays and expected outcome

Comment: @AlyHosny edited the post to add what you've suggested

Answer (score 0):

```
lidar = np.array([[1.1,2.03,28,2,0],[1.1,2.05,34,3,0],[1.2,2.09,5,1,0]])
depth = np.array([[1.1,2.05,33,7,0],[1.2,3.05,23,1,0],[1.5,1.95,5,5,1],[1.2,2.09,5,1,0]])

match = np.array([all(depth[:,0:2][i] == lidar[:,0:2][j]) for i in range(depth.shape[0]) for j in range(lidar.shape[0])]).reshape(depth.shape[0],lidar.shape[0]) # find where they match
#match = = [[all(depth[:,0:2][i] == lidar[:,0:2][j]) for j in range(lidar.shape[0])] for i in range(depth.shape[0])] # without reshaping

depth_idx , lidar_idx = np.where(match) # get the indices of the match

output = np.c_[lidar[lidar_idx] , depth[depth_idx][:,2:]]
```

another approach to get `match` through broadcasting and iterate only over 1 array

```
match = np.array([np.sum(depth[:,0:2][i] - lidar[:,0:2],axis=1) for i in range(depth.shape[0])])
depth_idx , lidar_idx = np.where(match==0)
```